# Accessiblity and labeling multiple buttons

Tags: accessibility, screen-reader

I'm working on a mobile app. I have a list with multiple groups and at the end of each group, there are some buttons. I'm not sure what the screen reader should say when focusing on the buttons.

The groups are something like this:

Name | Score | Increase | Decrease | Info

Increase, decrease and info are the buttons to increase, decrease the score and info opens a details page. The list will have anywhere from one to many groups (I don't expect there to be more than 10).

When each group of the list is focused, it reads the name and score together. So as you move across a group it reads:

"Name. Score" and then the buttons, "Increase", "Decrease, "Info"

My question is whether it should instead be:

"Name. Score" and then "Name. Increase", "Name. Decrease" and "Name Info"

Is it too repetitive? Or is it clearer to say which button goes with which group?

Once the button is tapped, the new score is announced as "Name. Score" again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`{Name}` Increase" would almost certainly be better, "Increase score for `{Name}`" would be even better.

The main reason for this is because with a screen reader it is easy to get disorientated (albeit an experienced screen reader user will soon find their place again in a couple of seconds) on a page, especially when navigating repetitive lists.

By labelling the controls in a way that associates them with the current row it makes it easy for screen readers to know they have ended up on the control they intended and not accidentally jumped to a different control. (depending on the device and screen reader used they may be navigating by Headings, Links, Buttons, Sections / Regions etc. or by scanning their finger over the page (where it is easy to accidentally select a control that was not intended) so linear relationships where a set of controls are under a certain heading etc. are less evident to screen reader users).

Although this may feel like you are adding a lot of information you have to bear in mind that most screen reader users will be listening at 200% to 300% read speeds and so it will not really affect them (plus they can cancel current speech easily).